# Need SQL To Count BOM Children Qty

Tags: sql

I am looking for an SQL query that will count the parts used.  Some of the parts are parent parts and have 1 or more child parts.  I need the query to count those as well.  There is only 1 level from parent to child, not multiple.  Here is sample data.

```
Table1
PartNumber  Type    Qty
abc01       ind     15
bsd90       ind     24
poi99       parent  10   (ind means individual part, no children)
```

```
Table2
(BOMs)
Parent      poi99   Qty Per Parent
Children    poi01   2
            poi02   1
            poi03   5
```

Desired End Result

```
PartNumber  Qty
abc01       15
bsd90       24
poi99       10
poi01       20
poi02       10
poi03       50
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something along the lines of the query below?

This query uses UNION to concat the results of 2 separate queries into one. In the second query I JOINed the 2 tables and then just used * to multiply the value in the second table by the value in the first.

Note: I made some assumptions about how your tables might look like. You're example of table2 was not really clear to me. You probably need to fill in some of the actual table- and columnnames.

```
SELECT t1.PartNumber, t1.Qty 
FROM Table1 t1

UNION

SELECT t2.PartNumber, t2.Gty * t1.Gty
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Id = t2.ParentId
```